# Rails: Authenticate two user types in one controller with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

I have two separate user models using Devise: Customer and Vendor

I'd like to use one controller in my application for a set of tasks with but unique to both users so I try authenticate like so

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_customer!...
    before_action :authenticate_vendor!...
...
end
```

I'd like to exclude one or the other from certain actions/views.

What the above does in my application though, for example, is if I log in as a vendor and try to go to a different action - it tries to authenticate a customer and vice versa.

Is there a work around for this? I'm considering setting up a new controller where-by I authenticate one of them there separately for the same model but it would have to have it's own views and all the duplication.

Is there a way to avoid going that route?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_customer!, if: :customer?
    before_action :authenticate_vendor!, if: :vendor?
...
end
```

The `customer?` and `vendor?` methods can be defined based on either some parameter's value or some value(eg. role) stored in DB.